# Karma + ui-router fails: Cannot read property 'isDefined' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, angular-ui, karma-runner

I am using `ui-router` in my Angular project. For testing, I am using `Karma` and `Jasmine`.

When running `Karma`, I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isDefined' of undefined
at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/examtesting/js/vendor/angular-ui-router.min.js:7
```

How do I get past this?

Here's the whole terminal:

```
patrickreck@Patricks-MacBook-Pro /A/M/h/examtesting> karma start karma.conf.js 
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.16 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
INFO [Chrome 35.0.1916 (Mac OS X 10.9.2)]: Connected on socket xtivwYEP-4sBQAeAlsMl with id 73870853
Chrome 35.0.1916 (Mac OS X 10.9.2) ERROR
  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isDefined' of undefined
  at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/examtesting/js/vendor/angular-ui-router.min.js:7
```

Comment: you might try loading the un-minified version of `angular-ui-router` and check out the problem in the console.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`isDefined` could possibly be a property of the `angular` variable. So maybe the angular library is not being loaded properly.

Can you post the Karma config file? Angular needs to be loaded before angular-ui-router.js.

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to mark my answer as correct, so I can get more internet points!

Comment: Of course, there's just a timer on it before I could do it :-)

Comment: This was the issue :>>Angular needs to be loaded before angular-ui-router.js. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 2):

Angular needs to be loaded before ui-router. In my case, the `<script src..>` for angular was below the ui-router.

```
<script src.. (angular)> above ui-router fixes this.
<script src.. (ui-router)>`
```